# Почему то не работает перетаскивание предметов в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Почему не работает метод с помощью которого можно перетаскивать объекты.
Вот сам код:

```
@FXML
    void pressCard(MouseEvent event){
        ImageView node = (ImageView) event.getSource();
        xOffset = event.getSceneX();
        yOffset = event.getSceneY();
    }
    @FXML
    void dragCard(MouseEvent e){
        ImageView node = (ImageView) e.getSource();
        node.setX(e.getScreenX() - xOffset);
        node.setY(e.getScreenY() - yOffset);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
float orgTranslateX, orgTranslateY;


EventHandler onMousePressed = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        orgSceneX = (float) t.getSceneX();
        orgSceneY = (float) t.getSceneY();
        orgTranslateX = (float) ((ImageView) (t.getSource())).getTranslateX();
        orgTranslateY = (float) ((ImageView) (t.getSource())).getTranslateY();
    }
};

EventHandler onMouseDragged = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        float offsetX = (float) t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
        float offsetY = (float) t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
        float newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
        float newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;

        ((ImageView)(t.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
        ((ImageView)(t.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);
    }
};
```